# Deleting a Node from a Linked List is not working

Tags: python, linked-list

My code below for deleting a node in a linked list is not working, as in it is deleting the wrong index of the index I want to delete instead.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.next=None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.tail=None

    def Addnode(self,data):
        new_node=Node(data)
        if self.head==None:
            self.head=new_node
        if self.tail!=None:
            self.tail.next=new_node
        self.tail=new_node

    def removenode(self,index):
        new_n=self.head
        count=0
        while count!=index:
            new_n=new_n.next
            count+=1
        new_n.next=new_n.next.next
    def Printlist(self):
        node=self.head
        while node!=None:
            print(node.data)
            node=node.next

List=LinkedList()
List.Addnode(1)
List.Addnode(2)
List.Addnode(3)
List.Addnode(4)
List.removenode(1)
List.Printlist()
```

So this should remove the Node that is at index 1, which is 2, but instead it removes 3, and prints 1,2,4 and not even 5 either? I am confused as why this is happening?

Comment: Perhaps adding the programming language tag would help

Comment: Is this in Python?

Comment: yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

You are going too far in your removal function. Let's walk through it, removing the first node (as in your code).

```
new_n=self.head
```

`new_n`  now points to the head node. This is what we want, so it is correct.

```
count=0
```

Initializes the count to zero. This is also correct, since the current node is node zero.

```
while count!=index:
    new_n=new_n.next
    count+=1
```

This is where we get the unexpected behavior. On the first iteration (since 0 != 1), we enter the loop. Now `new_n` points to the second element in the list (index 1), and `count`  is 1.

Now we try the loop condition again. `count`  is now equal to `index`  so we break out of the loop.

The current `new_n`  is now pointing to the second element in the list (index 1), so `new_n.next=new_n.next.next` changes the next element to be the element following its current next. This is the way to remove an element from a linked list, however we are off by one element (we traversed the list too far). In order to fix this, try the following code:

```
def removenode(self,index):
   # catch the edge condition where we're removing the first node
   if index==0 
        self.head = self.head.next 
   else
      new_n=self.head
      count=1
      while count!=index:
           new_n=new_n.next
          count+=1
      new_n.next=new_n.next.next
```

Disclaimer: I don't have Python on this computer, so I'm unable to test the code, but hopefully breaking it down this way helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for your detailed explanation! It works thank you!